# Referring xs:complexType in another complexType

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have two complex types declared as(the type SecurityRule is well defined):

```
<xs:complexType name="SecurityGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="rules" type="SecurityRule" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Template">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="tagsList" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="providerId" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="locationName" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now when I try to use these two complex types in a third complex type like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="CreateServerInputBean">
        <xs:element name="template" type="Template"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="securityGroup" type="SecurityGroup"></xs:element>
</xs:complexType>
```

The error I received is:

```
s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'CreateServerInputBean' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

Anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
<xs:complexType name="CreateServerInputBean">
<xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="template" type="Template"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="securityGroup" type="SecurityGroup"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

or with `<xs:choice> or <xs:all>` depending upon your requirement